Text in three js website, css3drenderer is being only rendererd half on mobile version
As you can see here the text is only being rendered half this is an example of the text i disply ..
export  const Fortress = `
  
    Fortress
  
  A 2D game where earth as a spaceship battles global threats. Inspired by "Space Invaders" with advanced weapons and tech.
  
  
    Programming & Tech:
      
        Built with JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas.
        Dynamic gameplay and immersive visuals.


  
  See images 
Back
`; ... and this is the code
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import * as THREE from "three";
    import {
      CSS3DRenderer,
      CSS3DObject,
    } from "three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js";
    import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
    import TWEEN from "@tweenjs/tween.js";
    import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
    import { WebGLRenderer } from "three";
    import { welcome, profileContent, skillsContent, projectsContent, Fortress, MyGymBro, Mathemello, Commerce, Disconnect, Rosetta, Portfolio, caroFortress, caroCommecre, caroMathe, caroGym, caroDisconnect, caroRosa, caroPort } from '../contentnew.js';
  
  
    let webGLRenderer;
    let container;
    let camera;
    let raycaster;
  
    let mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  
    let frontSide;
  
    let computer;
    let scene;
    let renderer;
  
    const cubeSize = 3000;
    const cameraDistance = cubeSize * 2;
    let cube;
  
  
    let isMobile = false;
    let width;
    let height;
    const start = `
   
  
  `;
  
  
  
    const cameraPositions = [
      {
        position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1850, 3050),
        lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      },
      {
        position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1850, 3050),
        lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      },
      {
        position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1850, 3050),
        lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      },
      {
        position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1850, 3050),
        lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      },
      {
        position: new THREE.Vector3(-100, 180, 4500),
        lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      },
      {
        position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1850, 3050),
        lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      },
    ];
  
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
    function moveToPosition(index) {
      const { position, lookAt } = cameraPositions[index];
      animateCamera(camera.position, position, lookAt);
    }
  
    function animateCamera(from, to, lookAt) {
      const duration = 4000;
      const start = { x: from.x, y: from.y, z: from.z };
      const end = { x: to.x, y: to.y, z: to.z };
  
      new TWEEN.Tween(start)
        .to(end, duration)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut)
        .onUpdate(() => {
          camera.position.set(start.x, start.y, start.z);
          camera.lookAt(lookAt);
        })
        .start();
    }
  
    function load3DModel() {
      const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  
      raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  
      window.addEventListener("click", onModelClick, false);
      // window.addEventListener("mousemove", onModelMove, false);
  
      loader.load(
        "/ibm.glb",
        function (gltf) {
          computer = gltf.scene;
          computer.position.set(-300, -2800, 1200); // Adjust position as needed
          computer.scale.set(7500, 6900, 3500); // Adjust scale as needed
          computer.rotation.y = -0.04;
  
          // computer.position.set(-300, -2000, 1200); // Adjust position as needed
          // computer.scale.set(4500, 3900, 500);
  
          scene.add(computer); // Add the model directly to the scene
  
          scene.add(computer);
  
          const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
          scene.add(ambientLight);
  
          if (!computer) {
            // console.warn("Model is not loaded yet, cannot add spotlight.");
            return;
          }
        },
        undefined,
        function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        },
      );
  
      function onModelClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
  
        // Scales mouse coordinates from -1.0 to 1.0 on canvas
        const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x =
          ((event.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left)) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y =
          -((event.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top)) * 2 + 1;
  
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  
        const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
  
        for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
          let object = intersects[i].object;
  
          // Traverse up the parent chain to check if any parent is the computer model
          while (object) {
            if (object === computer) {
              // Make sure 'model' refers to your computer model
              moveToPosition(4);
  
              return; // Exit the function once the computer model is found and actioned
            }
            object = object.parent;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  
    function updateFrontSideContent(content) {
      frontSide.innerHTML = content;
  
      const buttonActions = [
        () => updateFrontSideContent(Fortress),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(Commerce),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(MyGymBro),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(Mathemello),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(Disconnect),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(projectsContent),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(Rosetta),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(Portfolio),
  
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroFortress),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroCommecre),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroMathe),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroGym),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroDisconnect),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroRosa),
        () => updateFrontSideContent(caroPort),
      ];
  
      for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const myButton = document.getElementById(`my-button${i}`);
          if (myButton) {
            myButton.addEventListener("pointerdown", buttonActions[i - 1]);
  
            myButton.style.background = "none";
            myButton.style.border = "none";
            myButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
            myButton.style.display = "flex";
            myButton.style.flexDirection = "column";
            myButton.style.fontFamily = "'Press Start 2P', cursive";
            myButton.style.textAlign = "start";
            myButton.style.color = "#87CEFA";
  
            myButton.style.padding = "20px";
          }
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  
    function createCube() {
      cube = new THREE.Group();
      cube.position.set(-150, -500, -200);
      scene.add(cube);
  
      frontSide = document.createElement("div");
      frontSide.className = "cube-side front-side";
  
      ////// fade out fade in
      frontSide.style.opacity = "0";
  
      frontSide.style.visibility = "hidden";
      frontSide.style.transition = "opacity 0.3s ease-in-out";
  
      updateFrontSideContent(start);
  
      const object = new CSS3DObject(frontSide);
      object.position.z = cubeSize / 2;
      cube.add(object);
  
      createSide(frontSide, 0);
    }
  
    let activeSection = "";
  
    function selectSection(section) {
      activeSection = section;
  
      switch (section) {
        case "Info":
          updateFrontSideContent(personalInfoContent);
          break;
        case "profile":
          updateFrontSideContent(profileContent);
          break;
        case "skills":
          updateFrontSideContent(skillsContent);
          break;
        case "education":
          updateFrontSideContent(educationContent);
          break;
        case "experience":
          updateFrontSideContent(experienceContent);
          break;
        case "projects":
          updateFrontSideContent(projectsContent);
          break;
        case "interests":
          updateFrontSideContent(personalInterestsContent);
          break;
  
        default:
          console.log("Section not found");
      }
    }
  
    function createSide(element, idx) {
      element.style.width = `${3000}px`;
      element.style.height = `${3700}px`;
  
      element.style.display = "flex";
      element.style.flexDirection = "column";
  
      element.style.textAlign = "start";
      element.style.color = "#87CEFA";
      document.body.style.fontFamily = "'Press Start 2P', cursive";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
      document.body.style.color = "#fff";
  
      const relativeSize = 3000 / 2700;
      element.style.fontSize = `${relativeSize * 50}px`;
  
      element.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0,0)";
  
      const object = new CSS3DObject(element);
      const offset = 3000;
      object.position.set(
        idx === 4 ? offset : idx === 5 ? -offset : 0,
        idx === 2 ? offset : idx === 3 ? -offset : 0,
        idx === 0 ? offset : idx === 1 ? -offset : 0,
      );
      object.rotation.y = idx === 4 ? Math.PI / 2 : idx === 5 ? -Math.PI / 2 : 0;
    }
  
    function updateTextVisibility() {
      if (!computer) {
        // console.warn("Model is not loaded yet.");
        return;
      }
  
      // Assuming the screen's normal points along the computer model's local Z-axis
      const screenNormal = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
      screenNormal.applyQuaternion(computer.quaternion); // Apply the object's rotation
  
      const cameraDirection = new THREE.Vector3()
        .subVectors(camera.position, computer.position)
        .normalize();
  
      // Adjust the threshold based on your desired sensitivity
      const threshold = 0.5; // Adjust this value as needed
  
      if (screenNormal.dot(cameraDirection) > threshold) {
        // Camera is facing the screen
        frontSide.style.opacity = "1";
        frontSide.style.visibility = "visible";
      } else {
        // Camera is not facing the screen
        frontSide.style.opacity = "0";
        // frontSide.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }
  
    function sceneSetup() {
      // updateCameraPositions();
      // createMirror()
      width = container.clientWidth;
      height = container.clientHeight;
  
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
  
      webGLRenderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
      webGLRenderer.setSize(width, height);
      webGLRenderer.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
      container.appendChild(webGLRenderer.domElement);
  
      renderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(width, height);
      renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
      const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(100000, 10, 100000),
        new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x550000 }),
      );
      scene.add(floor);
      floor.position.set(-100, -1650, 400);
  
      const spotLightt = new THREE.SpotLight(
        "white",
        620,
        10000,
        Math.PI * 0.25,
        0.25,
        0.5,
      );
      spotLightt.position.set(0, 6000, 4000);
  
      scene.add(spotLightt);
  
      const spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(
        "orange",
        320,
        10000,
        Math.PI * 0.08,
        0.5,
        0.4,
      );
      spotLight2.position.set(-9000, 3000, 5000);
  
      scene.add(spotLight2);
  
      const spotLight3 = new THREE.SpotLight(
        "orange",
        320,
        10000,
        Math.PI * 0.08,
        0.5,
        0.4,
      );
      spotLight3.position.set(9000, 3000, 5000);
  
      scene.add(spotLight3);
    }
  
    function camerSetUp() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 1, 20000);
      camera.position.z = cameraDistance;
      camera.position.y = cameraDistance;
      camera.position.x = -cameraDistance;
  
      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enableDamping = true; // An animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
      controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
      controls.enableZoom = true; // Enable zooming
  
      controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // Minimum vertical rotation angle
      controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2; // Maximum vertical rotation angle
  
      controls.minDistance = 2980; // Minimum distance to target (zoom in boundary)
      controls.maxDistance = 4500;
    }
  
    function animate(webGLRenderer) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => animate(webGLRenderer));
      TWEEN.update();
      updateTextVisibility();
  
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
  
    function onWindowResize(webGLRenderer) {
      if (!container) return; // Add this line to prevent errors if container is null
  
      const width = container.clientWidth;
      const height = container.clientHeight;
  
      camera.aspect = width / height;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  
      renderer.setSize(width, height);
      webGLRenderer.setSize(width, height);
    }
  
    function terminal() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        const loading = document.getElementById("loading-screen");
  
        loading.style.display = "none";
  
        var navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
        moveToPosition(4);
        navbar.style.opacity = "1";
        navbar.style.visibility = "visible"; // Applied immediately
        navbar.style.transition = "opacity 0.9s ease, visibility 0s linear 0s";
  
        updateFrontSideContent(welcome);
      }, 2000);
    }
  
  
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
    onMount(() => {
  
      
    
      terminal();
      sceneSetup();
      camerSetUp();
      // createButtons();
      createCube();
      load3DModel();
  
      animate(webGLRenderer);
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => onWindowResize(webGLRenderer));
      document
        .getElementById("instagramIcon")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          window.open("https://instagram.com/m877ammar", "_blank");
        });
      document.getElementById("mail").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.location.href =
          "mailto:mohammedamaar165@gmail.com?subject=SubjectHere&body=BodyContentHere";
      });
  
      document.getElementById("git").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.open("https://github.com/Mohammed87FS", "_blank");
      });
      
      document.getElementById("linked").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohammed-al-hamadani-a88518302/", "_blank");
      });
  
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        // Update 'isMobile' based on screen width
        isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
  
        // Optional: Listen for window resize events to handle dynamic changes
        const handleResize = () => {
          isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
        };
  
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  
        // Cleanup function
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };}
  
  
  
    
    });
  
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  </script>
  
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"> -->
  
  <div
    style=" font-family: 'Press Start 2P'; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: black; color: orange; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; font-size: 24px; z-index: 9999;"
    class="terminal"
    id="loading-screen"
  >
    Loading...
  </div>
  
  {#if isMobile}
  <div
    style="
      font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: black;
      color: orange;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + 1vmin);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      z-index: 9999;
    "
    class="terminal"
    id="loading-screen"
  >
    This website is meant to be viewed on the desktop version only to enjoy the full experience :)
  </div>
  
  
  {/if}
  
  <div class="navbar">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events -->
    <div
      class:active={activeSection == "profile"}
      class:nav-item={activeSection != "profile"}
      on:click={() => {
        selectSection("profile");
      }}
    >
      About
    </div>
    <div
      class:active={activeSection == "skills"}
      class:nav-item={activeSection != "skills"}
      on:click={() => {
        selectSection("skills");
      }}
    >
      Skills
    </div>
  
    <div
      class:active={activeSection == "projects"}
      class:nav-item={activeSection != "projects"}
      on:click={() => {
        selectSection("projects");
      }}
    >
      Projects
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div
    bind:this={container}
    class="container"
    style="width: 100%; height: 88vh;"
  ></div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <img src="/linked2.svg" alt="linkedin Icon" id="linked" style="cursor:pointer;" />
  
    <img src="/git.svg" alt="github Icon" id="git" style="cursor:pointer;" />
  
    <img src="/email.svg" alt="email Icon" id="mail" style="cursor:pointer;" />
    <img
      src="/insta.svg"
      alt="Instagram Icon"
      id="instagramIcon"
      style="cursor:pointer;"
    />
  
  
  
   
  
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </footer>
  
  <style>
  
    .spacer {
      width: 4%; /* Adjust this width to control the shift */
      height: 100%;
      flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevents the spacer from shrinking */
    }
    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000000;
      color: white;
  
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 10px 0;
  
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  
    .footer img {
      height: 35px;
      width: auto;
      cursor: pointer;
      filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      margin: 0 10px;
    }
  
    .footer img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #000000; /* Classic NES black */
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      visibility: hidden;
      text-align: center;
  
      opacity: 0; /* Start invisible */
    }
    * .nav-item {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px 0; /* Space out the nav items */
      background-color: #000000; /* Bright contrast against the dark navbar */
      color: #ffffff; /* Dark text for readability */
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive; /* Pixelated font for the retro look */
      font-size: 1.2rem; /* Adjust size due to the typically large size of pixelated fonts */
      border-radius: 5px; /* Slightly rounded corners for each nav item */
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition:
        background-color 0.3s,
        color 0.3s,
        transform 0.1s; /* Smooth transitions for interactive effects */
    }
  
    .active {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive;
  
      font-size: 1.2rem; /* Corrected from font-size= to font-size: */
      color: #ffaa00;
  
      text-shadow:
        1px 1px 0 #ff6666,
        /* Lighter red for a subtler effect */ 2px 2px 0 #ff6666,
        3px 3px 0 #ff0000,
        4px 4px 0 #ff0000;
    }
  
    .nav-item:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #000000;
      /* Lighten the item on hover for an interactive feel */
    }
  
    .nav-item:active {
      transform: scale(0.95); /* Slight press effect on click */
    }
  </style>
  

i tried literally everything i am aware of, from changing the fontsize to more changes in different variables in the code i made... but nothing seems to have any connection with the problem, since the probelem also only emerges on phone and not even on the desktop version when i inspect and try to manipulate the screen size... i am gonnna provide u with the code i have.. i would be really glad if someone could help since i am pretty lost at this point ...
